# How do I control the speed of an animated GIF?

Tags: java, animation, gif, animated-gif

I would like to control the speed of an animated GIF in a  Java applet. Is there a way to do this? If not, is there a way to access the data of an animated GIF so the applet can draw the animation image by  image on its own?

Comment: *"How do I control the speed of an animated GIF in a Java applet?"*  Exactly the same way you might do it in an app. 'Applet' is therefore irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the frame rate is embedded into the GIF. You could somehow extract the images from the GIF, but that's harder than starting with the individual images and animating them in JS, which is harder than recreating the GIF with your preferred frame rate.

If you're going to use the GIF only once and the frame rate isn't going to change, just recreate the GIF. If you need to change the speed based on inputs from your applet, you could use the approach [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.applet/AnimApplet.html). It alternates **between** two gifs, but there's nothing stopping you from loading in PNGs and alternating through an Array of those.

Answer (score 1):

The animated GIF format is consists of data for each frame along with a delay value (how long to show that frame). The delay is separate for each frame, and is stored as two bytes and measures as hundred's of a second.

Netscape (back when it was the web), couldn't show the frames faster than 10 per second. So lots of tools just said screw it, and set delay for all the frames to 0. Lots of old gifs and old tools, have keep these screwed up frame delay times around.

With faster computers and browsers, they worked around this by checking if any of the frames had a delay <= 50ms (20+ fps). IF they did, the delay was increased to 100ms (10fps).

In principle, the best solution would be to just fix the GIF you're using to have accurate frame delays in them. If that isn't viable, use that same old workaround. Break the frames out of the animated GIF and do the animation yourself, defaults to a 100ms delay if the specified delay is <= 50ms. This will give you the same behavior as what you see in most web browsers.

Read about this a while ago. Think most of the details on mentioned on wikipedia (including the animated GIF format and the per frame delays). If it you really want some solid references, I can dig them for you.